# Audio recording does not work -- how to diagnose?

Tags: fedora, audio, recording

I used KRec to record some audio, but when I played it back I got nothing. What are the things I need to do to figure out where the problem is? My computer is a Dell OptiPlex DX620, Intel Pentium 4 3.00 GHz running Fedora 7 (Moonshine)

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to check the volume settings? It looks like the program for this in KDE is `kmix`.

(Yes, I know this is like asking if you remembered to plug in your computer and connect your monitor when you complain that the screen is blank, but everyone misses those steps once in a while...)

Comment: Indeed, sometimes to get audio output you need to set more than one volume control to a large enough value (and sometimes your mixer doesn't show all the necessary controls!). Input is usually simpler, but still, checking the volume(s) can be a nonobvious step.

Comment: In addition make sure that the module (or whatever it's called I don't mean kernel module) for input is turned on! alsa leaves everything off by default it seems.

Comment: I use Linux all the time to build software but I seldom use it as a desktop, so I'll try kmix tomorrow when I go back to work. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @gro any update?

Comment: @Tshepang, sorry I gave up. I don't work there anymore so don't have to worry about that anymore. Extremely happy with my MacBook now.

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to select the input device. Those controls are usually in extended settings in your mixer.